# order conformation mail not comming in magento , while newsleter - register mail come

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0

Order confirmation email not coming to a customer in Magento.
But newsletter - register email arrive to the customer.
So what exactly have a problem ?

Comment: when anyone place order in site , they not get any conformation mail . if they register in site then they get mail.

Comment: It might be an html error in the email template, and error in a module that hooks into the emails etc. Please check the magento and apache error logs for more information